# Java NIO UDP client with multiple servers

Tags: java, udp, nio

I'm building a UDP client that can communicate with a selection of different servers. Given that an NIO application involves using a single receive thread, how can I dispatch incoming datagrams to the correct part of my application? i.e. associate incoming packets with the outgoing packets.

In theory, when sending (or connecting?) to a server, it should be possible to get the source ip/port in the outgoing Datagram and then recognise incoming packets as their responses by inspecting the destination ip/port. (because: http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~ptw/teaching/IWT/transport-layer/source-destination.gif)

Most UDP client examples seem to assume a single server, so that identifying incoming datagrams as responses to outgoing datagrams is trivial, for example:

```
ByteBuffer textToEcho = ByteBuffer.wrap("blah");
ByteBuffer echoedText = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);

DatagramChannel datagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
datagramChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(REMOTE_IP, REMOTE_PORT));

while(true)
{
     int sent = datagramChannel.write(textToEcho);
     datagramChannel.read(echoedText);
}
```

Perhaps I could use multiple DatagramChannels and iteratively call read() on each, dispatching data to the appropriate to wherever my application is expecting responses?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dead-set on using just one channel (and one bound local port), you need to avoid using the `connect` and `write` methods.  Instead, use the `send` method.

1. Looping through your servers, use the `send` method for each server.  You may need to `rewind()` your byte buffer after each `send`... I'm not sure if `send` clones the buffer or not.
2. When all servers have been sent: In a loop, as long as there are servers that haven't responded, use `receive` to get both the data returned (buffer argument), and the server that returned it (the method return value).  Keep looping until the server list is exhausted, but you want to put a time-limit on the loop itself (for dead servers or lost packets)

Ideally in the receive loop, you want the receive method to block for a short period of time before timing out.  If you can't find a way to configure blocking, you could use non-blocking, and put a Thread.sleep in your loop instead.  Try to get timed blocking working though, that's the best way.

Comment: I think I follow you, but here is where there is a gap in my knowledge...

I understand that I can identify which server is returning the data by inspecting the ip address returned by receive(), because ip addresses are unique to the servers. But there may be multiple "streams" from my client going to the same server also. In that case, surely my application (client) needs to know the SOURCE ip and port of the outgoing port so that it can multiplex responses appropriately?
Assuming this is the correct approach, how would I get the source ip?

Comment: Why would you need the source IP?  Your client channel is bound to an IP and port, and anything sent to that IP and port will be picked up by your channel.  Everything you send & receive on that channel uses the same IP and port, so even if you could read the incoming destination info packet, it would always be the same.  There is nothing in UDP that helps differentiate between multiple conversations with the same server.  You would need to include that information in the payload yourself: making your own protocol.  It sounds like TCP would be a more suitable protocol for what you're doing.

Comment: "There is nothing in UDP that helps differentiate between multiple conversations with the same server." But I thought that by convention, outgoing packets have a source port and that their responses come back with this same port in the as the destination (as diagrammed here: http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~ptw/teaching/IWT/transport-layer/source-destination.gif). 
Surely this is what DatagramChannel.connect() uses to receive the appropriate appropriate response packets?
Perhaps this is possible in theory but that java doesn't provide the means for doing so.

Comment: @user1478842 Yes, the UDP port can differentiate.  But a single DatagramChannel can only send/receive on a single port.  If you want to use the UDP port to differentiate between servers, you need multiple DatagramChannels (one per server/local-port).  This is the approach I recommend.

Answer (score -2):

You should open a separate datagram channel to each server with which you wish to communicate, and hand-off that channel's management (reading/writing) to a separate thread.

Comment: So in that case I would have one thread per server on the client? I should add that the client is actually a server relaying messages to another local server on behalf of a client. Given that there will be many (actual, non-local) clients, I would like to avoid a thread for each one if possible.

Comment: Or maybe you meant that I could have dedicated read and write threads that send to multiple channels.
My impression with NIO-style programming is that we typically use a single DatagramChannel but multiplex somehow. I know how to multiplex when sending (simply specify the destination ip:port), but I don't know how to multiplex when receiving on the client with a single DatagramChannel, THIS is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: If you really want only one channel, then yes: one thread is the way to go.  One channel means one port, so you will have to examine the incoming packet source address to distinguish the server.  I'll add another answer to explain how.

Comment: One channel = one port, ok I hadn't realised this, that makes sense. Though, even if I used multiple channels for sending, surely its possible in theory to use one to receive all responses on multiple ports and multiplex them?